# An OGNL type converter demo

Tags: java, web, struts2, ognl

I got a demo to show how we can define customer type converter in struts2. The demo is so easy, input a string as "Tom,12" which represents user's name and age. The value will be placed into an user object. And console will output these values.
below is code:
JSP:

```
   <form action=testconvert method="post">
      Please enter your name<br/>
      <input type="text" name="user"/>
      <input type="submit" value="test"/>
   </form>
```

UserConverter: this is an user-defined converter.

```
public class UserConverter extends DefaultTypeConverter {
    @Override
    public Object convertValue(Map context, Object value, Class toType) {

        System.out.println("convertValue");
        if(User.class == toType)  
        {

            String[] str = (String[])value;
            String firstValue = str[0];

            System.out.println(firstValue);

            StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(firstValue, ",");

            String username = st.nextToken();
            int age =Integer.parseInt( st.nextToken());

            User user = new User();

            user.setUsername(username);
            user.setAge(age);

            return user;        
        }
        else if(String.class == toType) 
        {
            User user = (User)value;

            String username = user.getUsername();
            int age = user.getAge();

            String userInfo = "username: " + username + ", age: " + age;

            return userInfo;
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

I have properties file which is named as "testconvert-conversion.properties":

```
user=com.tutorialspoint.sconvert.UserConverter
```

Action file:

```
public class testconvert extends ActionSupport
{
    private User user;

    public User getUser()
    {
        System.out.println("getUser");
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user)
    {
        System.out.println("setUser");
        this.user = user;
    }

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("username: " + user.getUsername());
        System.out.println("age: " + user.getAge());

        System.out.println("execute");
        return SUCCESS;
    }
}
```

When I submit the value: "Tom,20" , the console output below content:

```
WARNING: Parameter [user] is not on the excludeParams list of patterns and will be appended to action!

convertValue
Tom,20
setUser
username: Tom
age: 20
execute
```

It has a warining, but it can output what I need.
Then I change the JSP file. I change the code as below:

```
<input type="text" name="user222"/>
```

I think the name of the input tag is not critical. But I'm wrong. I don't get the output correctly.

So My questions are:
1, what's warning meaning?

2, what can I do if I want the `<input>` name is user222?

Comment: See http://struts.apache.org/development/2.x/docs/exclude-parameters.html and http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/type-conversion.html

Comment: Have you checked the docs ?

http://struts.apache.org/release/2.3.x/docs/type-conversion.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use converter that not depends on property name in action class then you need to define application wide converter. That is done in `xwork-conversion.properties` file which is located in the root of the classpath.

```
your_package.User = com.tutorialspoint.sconvert.UserConverter
```